# Oracle plans for java plugin on chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, npapi

Since the Chrome development group warned that they would discontinue support for NPAPI in their browser, I have not seen movements in the Oracle development team.

Does anyone know if Oracle have plans to adapt its plugin to the plugins architecture for Chrome?